# How can I show loader when I click on submit button in AMP form?

Tags: amp-html

I have AMP form which passes the data to another page(eg. `xyz.php`). But `xyz.php` took 5 sec to submit the form. Rather than showing form, how can I show loader on AMP forms?

Answer (score 3):

If you're making use of the `amp-mustache` templates you can use with `amp-forms` to display a success or error message, there is one called `submitting`. This pops up once the user hits submit and remains until a `submit-success` or `submit-error` is rendered.

```
<div submitting>
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    MESSAGE OR LOADING GIF HERE
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that mustache is optional here - if you just want to show a loader, you can put it in the div directly, without the template tag.